# JPQL View returning duplicates

Tags: database, jpa, view, duplicates, jpql

I have created a Java entity (in Eclipse) based on a view I have set up on my database. The set up of the entity works as tested on my glassfish server and also via the flex application that I have running that references the methods and classes therein the deployed webservice.

The only problem is the amount of rows is correct, but the values being returned are all duplicates! I can't fathom why this is happening and have found next to nothing on referencing views on the net other than that it should work much the same as a table...it does but it returns duplicates!

As a test I created a table with all the same columns / data etc as the view and pointed the JPA entity at that - voila...no duplicates!

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here please?

Here's the code!

```
EntityManager em = null;
BigDecimal pId = new BigDecimal(conId);


try {
em = emf.createEntityManager();
String applicationQueryString = "select c from VDisc c where c.dCorId = :conId";

Query contdetQuery = em.createQuery(applicationQueryString);
contdetQuery.setParameter("conId",pId);

List list = contdetQuery.getResultList();
VDisciplines[] disc = new VDisciplines[list.size()];
disc = (VDisciplines[]) list.toArray(disc);

return disc;
```

Answer (score 3):

How have you mapped your Entity to the view, and what did you define as the Id?  Also how are you defining/executing the query?

If you define some field that was not unique as the Id, then you would get duplicate objects for the same Id.

You could try using a native SQL query for the raw data to ensure it is being returned correctly from the database.

Comment: James - thanks for getting back to me mate. I thought this might be to do with the id thing...I had to remove the @Id annotation becuase every time I ran my query "select c from VDisc c where c.dCorId = :conId" it kept saying it didnt know what the "ID" field was in the select query as in "SELECT ID, CON_ID...". I assume it's to do with this? The problem is, as it is a view, there is no unique identifier in the view, just amixture of, ids and names that have been bulked together!

Comment: Include your VDisc class, it must still have an @Id or you would be getting an error.  If there is truly no unique set of fields in the view, then mark all of your attributes with @Id.

Answer (score 0):

The @Id annotation generates a cache of that record, if in your database you have other records with that same value for the Id (that is, it is not a unique identifier), JPA ignores them since it works with the cached value ( as it should be as long as the id is unique)